# CSS Dark Opacity

Tags: css

Is it possible to keep the background dark while adding opacity? I'm trying to create an input that looks like the image added. Every time I set the background to #000 and add opacity, the background starts to turn gray instead of staying black and becoming transparent.

[image]

Edit:

For everyone telling me to use:

```
 background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
```

This is the result (doesn't work)[image]

Edit 2:

Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/n7aob2yd/1/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157944/discussion-on-question-by-user2465134-css-dark-opacity).

Answer (score 3):

The last value `0.5` is the alpha channel.

```
.selector {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is correct. You see gray because the background is white. Try using a background like the one in your screenshot and you'll see that it works. And don't use `opacity` because it will apply it to everything, including the text. Now, try using a background color that matches the background image, in this case, a dark blue. Maybe that's what's missing.